# How to sort a multidimensional array of objects by property value in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, sorting, ecmascript-6

I have the following array:

```
const result = [
  [{value: 123, parentID: 1}, {value: 'string123', parentID: 2}],
  [{value: 54764, parentID: 1}, {value: 'string321', parentID: 2}],
  [{value: 321, parentID: 1}, {value: 'string565632', parentID: 2}],
]
```

and I need to sort this, multidimensional array based on the value, but which object to select is based on `parentID`.

What I have tried so far:

```
const parentID = 1;
const sortedResult = result.filter((row) => {
  const selectedColumn = row.find((column) => column.parentID === parentID));
  return _.orderBy(selectedColumn, ['value'], ['asc']);
});
```

but this isn't working, any ideas what could?

Desired output would be:

```
[
  [{value: 123, parentID: 1}, {value: 'string123', parentID: 2}],
  [{value: 321, parentID: 1}, {value: 'string565632', parentID: 2}],
  [{value: 54764, parentID: 1}, {value: 'string321', parentID: 2}],
]
```

Comment: @CBroe so all of the objects have a `value` property and a `parentID` property. In order to choose by which object to sort, you would use `parentID`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To sort an array, you should use `Array.prototype.sort`.

Make a helper function that, given an array item (which, here, is itself an array), finds the object with the `parentID`, and extracts its value. In the `.sort` callback, call that helper function on both items being compared, and return the difference:

```js
const parentID = 1;
const getValue = arr => arr.find(item => item.parentID === parentID).value;
const result = [
  [{value: 123, parentID: 1}, {value: 'string123', parentID: 2}],
  [{value: 54764, parentID: 1}, {value: 'string321', parentID: 2}],
  [{value: 321, parentID: 1}, {value: 'string565632', parentID: 2}],
];
result.sort((a, b) => getValue(a) - getValue(b));
console.log(result);
```